# Total effects read the same in mediation analyses

Tags: mediation

I was trying to conduct a mediation analysis to assess the effects of three different mediators between the IV and the DV. However, despite the a paths, b paths and c' paths being different for all of them, the total effects are the same (i.e, the total effect of IV on DV remains the same of each of the different mediators). I cannot figure out why that is, and would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that the total effect is the same for the different intervening variables. Lets say you are looking at the effect of X on Y and want to know how much of that effect works throught the intervening variables Z1, Z2 and Z3. The total effect of X on Y is that effect without adjusting for the intervening variable(s). So it does not matter if you look at the indirect effect through Z1, Z2, or Z3; the total effect will always be the same.